# How to pass a value in window resize to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn how to pass one value within a window resize event, to a function, but I do not know what I am doing wrong.  Basically everytime the window resizes, I want the scrollHeight to go to another function where I can view that value on click.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
var mheight = $('#wrapper')[0].scrollHeight;
smoothscroll(mheight);
});

function smoothscroll(mvalue) {
$mheight = this.mvalue;

if ($mheight < 3000) {
$(selector).on('click',function() {
console.log('show me my latest scroll height value for larger screens' + $mheight);
});
} else {
console.log('show me my current scroll height value for smaller screens' + $mheight);
}

}
```

...but for some reason my value always comes up as undefined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
function smoothscroll(mvalue) {
   $mheight = this.mvalue;
   ....
}
```

To

```
function smoothscroll(mvalue) {
   $mheight = mvalue; // you don't need `this`, cause mvalue has passed by argument
   ....
}
```

Actually you can use `mvalue` directly without cache it to `$mheight`.

Complete code:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var mheight = $('#wrapper')[0].scrollHeight;
    smoothscroll(mheight);
});

function smoothscroll(mvalue) {
    if (mvalue < 3000) {
        $(selector).on('click', function () {
            console.log('show me my latest scroll height value for larger screens' + mvalue);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('show me my current scroll height value for smaller screens' + mvalue);
    }

}
```